# How to use map inside logstash? (Mysql to Elastic search)

Tags: mysql, logstash

So my ending goal, Combine all data provided by mysql. here is the data im working with

```
| shard| communityId| postId|json|
|:---- |:------:| -----:|-----:|
| BIGINT| VAR64| VAR32|{valid json with nested encoded json}|
```

So basically, one shard could look like

```
1,cid,pid,{title:"123"}
```

and the other one could look like this

```
1,cid,pid,{desc:"desc here"}
```

my ending goal is to combine everything inside logstash (via a simple select query via mysql, dont want to use groupconcat). I have tried dropping the event, canceling the event etc and i dont know where im going wrong. here is my jdbc code:

```
input {
  jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "/usr/mysql-connector-j-utf8.jar" #valid
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://*/table"
    jdbc_user => "*"
    jdbc_password => "*"
    schedule => "* * * * *" # Schedule for querying data (adjust as needed)
    statement => "SELECT * FROM sharded"
  }
}

filter {
  # Ensure events are sorted by 'communityId' and 'postId'
  ruby {
    code => "
      event.set('[@metadata][sort_key]', [event.get('communityId'), event.get('postId')].join('-'))
    "
  }

  # Aggregate events based on 'communityId' and 'postId'
  aggregate {
    task_id => "%{communityId}-%{postId}"
    code => "
      map['communityId'] = event.get('communityId')
      map['postId'] = event.get('postId')
      map['combined_data'] ||= []
      map['combined_data'].push(JSON.parse(event.get('data')))
      event.cancel()"
    push_previous_map_as_event => false
    timeout => 3 # Adjust the timeout as needed (in seconds)
    timeout_tags => ['aggregated']
  }

  # Use a conditional to filter out events without 'combined_data'
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
      hosts => ["elasticsearch-container:9200"]
      index => "collections"
      document_id => "%{[@metadata][sort_key]}" # Use lowercase 'postId'
      action => "update"
      doc_as_upsert => true
    }
    stdout {
    codec => rubydebug
  }
}
```

Comment: I have two questions: 1) is the result set of your SQL query sorted, i.e. all `communityId/postId` pairs come one after another ? 2) How many CPUs and how many workers are you using (the `aggregate` filter only works with a single worker)?

Comment: no they are not sorted. they are just randomly selected. I have access to 12 CPU threads and and only have one worker. my code so far (docker + logstash) [here](https://gist.github.com/Nolanrulesroblox/bd0184d7b2350a466b484e464bf7d265)

Comment: based on many factors, would it be better just to write a insert script in python or c?

Comment: The problem if they are not sorted is that all `communityId/postId` rows must be processed within the 3s timeout and you cannot guarantee that. If you sort by `communityId/postId` it's much more likely that it will work the way you expect. Also you really need to make sure to start Logstash with a single worker (i.e. `-w 1`)

Comment: I wound up just writing an importer in python. after the main python script gets the mysql data, combines the rows as needed, then spawns processes to do the other work needed

Comment: Glad you figured out another solution